# Sup and inf extended question - applying the definition to prove lemmas

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a non-empty bounded set where inf($S$)$=a\geq 0$ and sup($S$)$=b$. Let $T=\{z^2:z\in S\}$.

(a) Show that $a^2$ and $b^2$ are respectively upper and lower bounds for $T$, and therefore that inf($T$)$\geq a^2$ and sup($T$)$\leq b^2$.

(b) Suppose $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence for which $x_n\in S$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Prove that $a\leq x\leq b$.

(c) Show from the definition of sup and inf that given any $h>0$ there exists $x,y\in S$ such that $x<a+h$ and $y>b-h$. Putting $h=\frac{1}{n}$, and applying the Sandwich theorem, prove that there are sequences $a_n,b_n$ such that $a_n\rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$.

I have proved the first part of (a), but surely the part regarding inf and sup follows immediately? What could I say to justify this? For part (b) I said that if $x_n$ converges to $x$ then by definition of convergence we have $x-\varepsilon<x_n<x+\varepsilon$. However I don't know how to formalise the statement that $inf(S)\leq x_n\leq sup(S)$. Furthermore, for part (c) I would think that the statement is literally the definition of inf and sup so requires little comment. I struggled to use the sandwich theorem to prove the statement regarding sequences though:(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second part of a) follows from the fact the infimum is the greatest lower bound  and the supremum is the lowest upper bound.

You can take limits on both sides of an inequality.  So letting $n \to \infty$ in $\inf S \leq x_n \leq \sup S$ gives $\inf S \leq x \leq \sup S$.

In the last part we have $a \leq x_n<a+\frac  1 n$ for some $n$ (with $x_n \in S$) . Now $|x_n-a| \leq \frac 1 n $ so $x_n \to a$. Similar argument gives  a sequence converging to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it follows immediately from the definitions of supremum and infimum.
2. Suppose that $x<a$. Then there is a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies|x-x_n|<a-x$. But then$$x_n-x=-(x-x_n)\leqslant|x-x_n|<a-x,$$and so $x_n<a$, which is impossible.
3. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $a\leqslant a_n<a+\frac1n$, and so, by the Sandwich theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$.